# How can I increase the size of form text boxes?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to implement a simple feedback form for my site. However, the boxes are very small and don't really match the theme of my site at all. I have tried increasing text size and margin with CSS, but I can't seem to make them larger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<form action="form" method="POST" class="formone">
    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='John Doe' /><br/>
    <input type='text' name='message' placeholder='Your message'/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS, and combine it with the HTML in a runnable snippet to demonstrate, and describe in what way it's not doing what you expect?

Comment: Please include a [mre] which shows your attempts. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon with `<>` in the toolbar) to provide that.

Comment: Are you trying to increase they size of the text inside, or rather the amount of space to type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify it by giving them a class and then defining the font-size for those classes.

For example:

```css
.one{
font-size: 20px;
}
.two {
font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form action="form" method="POST" class="formone">
    <input class="one" type='text' name='name' placeholder='John Doe' /><br/>
    <input class="two" type='text' name='message' placeholder='Your message'/><br/>
    <input class="three" type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

I hope it helps.

Edit:

You can also try using inline style like this if it's not working due to some other style statement overriding this:

```html
<form action="form" method="POST" class="formone">
    <input style="font-size:20px !important;" type='text' name='name' placeholder='John Doe' /><br/>
    <input style="font-size:30px !important;" type='text' name='message' placeholder='Your message'/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: From the OP: "I have tried increasing text size and margin with CSS, but I can't seem to make them larger."

Comment: try adding !important to the style

Comment: or you can also add inline style

Comment: i have edited the answer, check the second snippet at end

Comment: the edited answer works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use textarea and using text area you can set height and width of it.

```
 <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">
The cat was playing in the garden.
</textarea>
```

In text area rows and cols are set as default textarea size and it is expandable.

As you have used `<input type='text'/>` It does not holds property of height and width so you cannot change it with css.

For better understanding refer these two links : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_width.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Hope it helps

Thanks